# UITableViewCells Not Appearing From Data Pulled From Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model that contains all the attributes for the cells. I am able to submit data to Firebase (From different VC) but not retrieve and load data into cells from Skills VC, in fact that tableView won't even reflect the size of the cells which I have set.

I believe its to do with the way firebase is being configured, when I use FirebaseApp.configure() I get a lldb crash. When I perform a check, error get printed.(Screenshots at bottom of post). I have attached all code which retrieves and load into table view below. Any help you greatly be appreciated as I am very stuck.

**Configure Firebase**

```
if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
  FirebaseApp.configure()
}else{
print("error")
}
```

**Class Model**

```
class attributesForCell {

var ID: String?
var Name: String?
var Category: String?
//var Rank: Int?
var Description: String?

init(ID: String?, Name: String?, Category: String?, Description: String?){ 
//RANK REMOVED FOR NOW
    self.ID = ID
    self.Name = Name
    self.Category = Category
    //self.Rank = Rank
    self.Description = Description
    }
```

**Main View Controller** - Skills. I have doubled checked that cell identifier is correct in MainStoryboard and that Class names match for the VC and Cell. I have also set the delegate & datasource for the tableView.

```
class Skills: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var refSkill: DatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var skillTableView: UITableView!

var SkillList = [attributesForCell]()//load Model Class

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection`section: Int) -> Int {
    return SkillList.count //return number of item in Skill List
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let skillInCell: attributesForCell 

    skillInCell = SkillList[indexPath.row] //specefic row

    cell.LabelCategoryOfSkill.text = skillInCell.Category
    cell.LabelNameOfSkill.text = skillInCell.Name //set the text to the 
    specefic row
    cell.LabelDescOfSkill.text = skillInCell.Description

    return cell
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    skillTableView.dataSource = self
    skillTableView.delegate = self

    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    refSkill = Database.database().reference().child("skill"); 
    refSkill.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0{ //check if there is data to display

            self.SkillList.removeAll() //clear model

            for skills in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                let skillsObject = skills.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                let skillName = skillsObject?["Name"]
                let categoryskill = skillsObject?["Category"]
                let descriptionSkill = skillsObject?["Description"]
                let skillID = skillsObject?["ID"]

                let skillPopulate = attributesForCell(ID: skillID as! 
                String?, Name: skillName as! String?, Category: categoryskill 
                as! String?, Description: descriptionSkill as! String?)

                self.SkillList.append(skillPopulate)
            }
            self.skillTableView.reloadData()//reload all data in table to 
             reflect changes

        }
    })


}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14NXFtvmXQo4np1yRqVslNj2EQ5WWPnCQ/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3kkASxoOpxj1z58lleQf5LaGinU8OqU/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14h17o7ZTVL-Pnr0SD2fNIzCaqAMyCDOq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is the call to `reloadData` being reached? Does `self.SkillList` have the expected data in it by the time `reloadData` is reached?

Comment: Try to reload tableview on main thread like this => DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

Answer (score -1):

You are reloading table view data before the firebase request is completed.

You have to put the reload method into a completionHandler() to be execute only when the request is fully completed.

Comment: The code in the question is properly calling `reloadData` within the async completion handler after updating the data model.